# Run an array of sagas effect sequentially

Tags: redux, generator, yield, redux-saga

I am trying to yield an array of saga effects sequentially.
The idea is that `yield all([call(foo), call(bar])` will run `call(foo)` and `call(bar)` in parallel (or at least in a pseudo-parallel fashion).

However, I want my sagas to run sequentially, meaning that I want to wait for `foo` to end before lauching `bar` (this way I can cancel the process).

This array of call is generated dynamically, so I can hard write a series of `yield`. What is the correct syntax in this case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The redux-saga [documentation](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/SequencingSagas.md) has an example of sequencing sagas.

If you have an array of calls, simply yield these in your saga. For example:

```
// Some array containing call objects
let calls = [...];

// Call each in order they are present in the array
for (let c of calls) {
  yield c
}
```

Comment: Hi, I indeed ended up using something similar using a for loop. I expected a smaller syntax using `forEach` or `map` though. I will encapsulate this into a homemade effect to get a nicer syntax, like `sequence([someArray])`.

Comment: Having your own `sequence` effect is probably best if you want something nice to read like `yield sequence(calls)`. There's no much difference in terms of code with a for loop compared to `forEach`. However, you can't `yield` except in the generator function, hence why you can't use `forEach`.